Maui Blazor Hybrid App won't publish to iOS: Link.semaphore error
I'm new to the MAUI world and have been struggling for a few days trying to publish my app to iOS. It publishes fine to Windows and Android, but not for iOS.
Following some posts, I've upgraded my Visual Studio Community 2022 to the latest version (17.11.3) and I am using a VMWare Mac with Sonoma 14.6.1 and XCode 15.4. They are pairing fine.
I'm trying to publish using powershell, since I read the VS interface is bad, using the following command:
dotnet publish D:\Dev\MBHA\MBHA\MBHA.csproj -f net8.0-ios -c Release -p:ArchiveOnBuild=true -p:TargetPlatform=arm64 -p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64 -p:ServerAddress=192.168.211.128 -p:ServerUser=USERNAME -p:ServerPassword=PASSWORD -p:TcpPort=58181 -p:_DotNetRootRemoteDirectory=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/

After many issues, which I could solve, I decided to forget about my app and created a new plain MAUI Blazor Hybrid Project under a plain new Solution.
Trying to publish it has the same issues which makes me think that something is wrong with my dev environment. I've searched here and in StackOverflow without success.
The code can be found here: https://github.com/iFelinto/MAUI-Blazor-Hybrid-App
Below is the message I get:

C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Windows.Sdk.net8.0_17.5\17.5.8030\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.After.targets(364,3): error : MessagingException: The post for client anonymous52f11260a5 on topic xvs/build/1.14.0.6/execute-task/MBHA/45c47fd002fILLink has been cancelled [D:\Dev\MBHA\MBHA.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Windows.Sdk.net8.0_17.5\17.5.8030\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.After.targets(364,3): error : OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled. [D:\Dev\MBHA\MBHA.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Windows.Sdk.net8.0_17.5\17.5.8030\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.After.targets(364,3): error :  [D:\Dev\MBHA\MBHA.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Windows.Sdk.net8.0_17.5\17.5.8030\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.After.targets(406,3): error MSB3371: The file "obj\Release\net8.0-ios\ios-arm64\linked\Link.semaphore" cannot be created. Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Dev\MBHA\obj\Release\net8.0-ios\ios-arm64\linked\Link.semaphore'. [D:\Dev\MBHA\MBHA.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]

It is important to mention that this is only happening with the Release version. Debug, runs fine on Simulators in all platforms.
Any ideas on what may be the issue here?

You may try Clearing the Broker, IDB, Build, and Designer Agents on the Mac
